# Getting Vulkan to support dedicated NVIDIA card on a laptop with AMD CPU

Tags: nvidia, xorg, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, vulkan

I have been trying for many hours now to run a Vulkan application on my discrete NVIDIA GPU. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on an ASUS ZenBook Pro K53SV, which has an NVIDIA RTX 3050 Ti Mobile GPU. The GPU registers as a 3D adapter:

```
$ lspci -k
...
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobile]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
...
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne (rev c4)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Cezanne
        Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
        Kernel modules: amdgpu
...
```

I am getting into GPGPU computing and I would like to run a Vulkan-based application on my dedicated GPU. However, Vulkan does not normally detect it:

```
$ vulkaninfo --summary
Can't open bumblebee display.
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : loader_scanned_icd_add: ICD libnv_vulkan_wrapper.so.1 doesn't support interface version compatible with loader, skip this ICD.
WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.
==========
VULKANINFO
==========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.3.204


Instance Extensions: count = 19
-------------------------------
VK_EXT_acquire_drm_display             : extension revision 1
VK_EXT_acquire_xlib_display            : extension revision 1
VK_EXT_debug_report                    : extension revision 10
VK_EXT_debug_utils                     : extension revision 2
VK_EXT_direct_mode_display             : extension revision 1
VK_EXT_display_surface_counter         : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_device_group_creation           : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_display                         : extension revision 23
VK_KHR_external_fence_capabilities     : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities    : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_external_semaphore_capabilities : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_get_display_properties2         : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2 : extension revision 2
VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2       : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_surface                         : extension revision 25
VK_KHR_surface_protected_capabilities  : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_wayland_surface                 : extension revision 6
VK_KHR_xcb_surface                     : extension revision 6
VK_KHR_xlib_surface                    : extension revision 6

Instance Layers: count = 3
--------------------------
VK_LAYER_MESA_device_select Linux device selection layer                         1.2.73   version 1
VK_LAYER_MESA_overlay       Mesa Overlay layer                                   1.2.199  version 1
VK_LAYER_PRIMUS_PrimusVK    Primus-vk - https://github.com/felixdoerre/primus_vk 1.2.0    version 1

Devices:
========
GPU0:
        apiVersion         = 4202700 (1.2.204)
        driverVersion      = 1 (0x0001)
        vendorID           = 0x10005
        deviceID           = 0x0000
        deviceType         = PHYSICAL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
        deviceName         = llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits)
        driverID           = DRIVER_ID_MESA_LLVMPIPE
        driverName         = llvmpipe
        driverInfo         = Mesa 22.0.1 (LLVM 13.0.1)
        conformanceVersion = 0.0.0.0
        deviceUUID         = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
        driverUUID         = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
GPU1:
        apiVersion         = 4206796 (1.3.204)
        driverVersion      = 92274689 (0x5800001)
        vendorID           = 0x1002
        deviceID           = 0x1638
        deviceType         = PHYSICAL_DEVICE_TYPE_INTEGRATED_GPU
        deviceName         = AMD RADV RENOIR
        driverID           = DRIVER_ID_MESA_RADV
        driverName         = radv
        driverInfo         = Mesa 22.0.1
        conformanceVersion = 1.2.7.1
        deviceUUID         = 00000000-0500-0000-0000-000000000000
        driverUUID         = 414d442d-4d45-5341-2d44-525600000000
```

Reading [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Vulkan) I understand that I may have some luck with something called [primus_vk](https://github.com/felixdoerre/primus_vk). I fiddled around all afternoon installing the right drivers and getting Bumblebee to succeed in running a simple application like Firefox (apparently, this is necessary for primus_vk to work). In fact:

```
$ optirun --status
Bumblebee status: Ready (3.2.1). X inactive. Discrete video card is likely on.
```

And `optirun firefox` runs correctly, even though the log shows messages from amdgpu, which is weird:

```
Gtk-Message: 19:03:56.447: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 19:03:56.448: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
amdgpu: os_same_file_description couldn't determine if two DRM fds reference the same file description.
If they do, bad things may happen!
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
Missing chrome or resource URL: resource://gre/modules/UpdateListener.jsm
Missing chrome or resource URL: resource://gre/modules/UpdateListener.sys.mjs
```

The objective is to successfully use `pvkrun`. `pvkrun firefox` yields the same output as when using optirun, but sadly `pvkrun vulkaninfo --summary` outputs

```
primus: fatal: failed to load any of the libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

and hangs without terminating. I don't know if it's relevant, but `optirun vulkaninfo --summary` is terminated by a SEGV.
I tried `grep`'ing the paths mentioned above in the whole filesystem, but I found nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here are the relevant APT packages I have installed:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep nvidia
bumblebee-nvidia/jammy,now 3.2.1-27 amd64 [installato, automatico]
libnvidia-cfg1-515/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [installato, automatico]
libnvidia-compute-515/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [installato, automatico]
linux-objects-nvidia-510-5.15.0-25-generic/jammy,now 5.15.0-25.25 amd64 [installato, automatico]
linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-25-generic/jammy,now 5.15.0-25.25 amd64 [installato, automatico]
nvidia-dkms-515/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [installato]
nvidia-kernel-common-515/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [installato]
nvidia-kernel-source-515/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [installato, automatico]
nvidia-prime/jammy,jammy,now 0.8.17.1 all [installato]
nvidia-primus-vk-common/jammy,now 1.6.1-1 amd64 [installato, automatico]
nvidia-primus-vk-wrapper/jammy,now 1.6.1-1 amd64 [installato, automatico]
nvidia-utils-515/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [installato]
primus-vk-nvidia/jammy,now 1.6.1-1 amd64 [installato]
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [installato]

$ apt list --installed | grep bumblebee
bumblebee-nvidia/jammy,now 3.2.1-27 amd64 [installato, automatico]
bumblebee/jammy,now 3.2.1-27 amd64 [installato, automatico]

$ apt list --installed | grep vk
libprimus-vk1/jammy,now 1.6.1-1 amd64 [installato, automatico]
nvidia-primus-vk-common/jammy,now 1.6.1-1 amd64 [installato, automatico]
nvidia-primus-vk-wrapper/jammy,now 1.6.1-1 amd64 [installato, automatico]
primus-vk-nvidia/jammy,now 1.6.1-1 amd64 [installato]
primus-vk/jammy,jammy,now 1.6.1-1 all [installato, automatico]
```

### EDIT 1

I noticed that my Xorg log contains the following lines:

```
[   274.008] (II) Loading sub module "glxserver_nvidia"
[   274.008] (II) LoadModule: "glxserver_nvidia"
[   274.008] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module glxserver_nvidia
[   274.008] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to load module "glxserver_nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[   274.008] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the GLX module; please check in your X
[   274.008] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     log file that the GLX module has been loaded in your X
[   274.008] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     server, and that the module is the NVIDIA GLX module.  If
[   274.008] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     you continue to encounter problems, Please try
[   274.008] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     reinstalling the NVIDIA driver.
[   274.008] (II) NVIDIA: The X server does not support PRIME Render Offload.
```

I could not understand how to fix this problem with this `glxserver_nvidia` module, nor do I understand whether the last line is independent of the problem. By the way, could switching to Wayland solve the problem?

Comment: Do you have `bbswitch-dkms` and `acpi-call` installed? It is the replacement of `bumblebee` iirc. Add its modules and  change PMmethod from auto to bbswtich. It shoud then work but I can not check (as I do not have an RTX ;) )

Comment: What is the application you are trying to run?

Comment: I am trying to develop an application that uses compute shaders to parallelize a task.

Comment: Check if your driver is the latest version. I have RTX3050 and it works with Vulkan.

Comment: I have installed version 515 of the driver.

Answer (score 2):

I was wrong about the driver being installed. While I had installed all the NVIDIA-related packages listed in the question, I had not, in fact, installed `nvidia-driver-515`.